# A Difficult Job

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, story

My plumber gave me a perilous job--his figurines had been stolen (3). I had to endure Ian's sobbing before he would tell me the problem under his feet (2). It turns out the girl he dated had taken his possessions, leaving only cheese in the fridge (2).

After my day's investigations, some ice-cream felt sublime (1). No barriers remained, and my main goal had been met (2). When Ian asked how things were going, I told him the day had been ________.

note: The numbers do not refer to the length of a word.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The day had been ...

> ... **fruitful**.

Why?

> Each sentence contains as many names of fruit as indicated by the number in parentheses. The fruit are included phonetically, so the spelling in the sentence may differ:
>
>  My **plum**ber gave me a **per**ilous job – his **fig**urines had been stolen.
>  I had to en**dure** **Ian**'s sobbing before he would tell me the prob**lem** **un**der his feet.
>  It turns out the girl he **date**d had taken his possessions, leaving on**ly** **chee**se in the fridge.
>
>  After my day's investigations, some ice-cream felt sub**lime**.
>  No **barriers** remained, and my **main** **go**al had been met.

Comment: Oh ! – Elephant Child's brothers

Comment: I can't work out how the fourth item or the next to last item satisfy the explanation.

Comment: @phoog: It's "en[**dure Ian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durian)'s" and "[**barriers**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berries)". (That last one may be a stretch, because the final "r" seems to be in the way.)

Comment: Oh I see.  I'd never heard of the former.  For the latter, not only the final R is a problem, but the vowel in the first syllable (in my experience, many non-native speakers from Europe think that these are the same vowel, but my not recognizing the connection here is a good example of how they are not).

Comment: I was going for the first two syllables of "barrier" only. That seemed close enough, so I added the word.